# help with using the Unity Web API for my website

Tags: 12.10, webapps, javascript

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.04/javascript/index.html), but when clicking on the '**executing this now**' on that site nothing happens, i have put up this code [here](http://jebster.net/api/)  press (CTRL+U) to see the code and that doesn't work either.

Facebook, Youtube and others websites work, so why doesn't that tutorial work?

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to work fine in Firefox. Please make sure your using Firefox for testing as it seems to be setup by default. Also, make sure that your allowing web apps.

When going to your example page, I got the "allow warning" and then the icon in the Unity area. I did not get the notification, but that is probably system settings.

Comment: ah, i just thought it would work with Chromium as i installed the webapps extension and the webapps for Facebook and others worked. do you know how to get it work with Chromium also?

Comment: Soory I do not.